# When we say that a 51% control of total computation power could lead to a successful Sybil attack, do we refer to miners or nodes?

Tags: blockchain, mining, nodes, bitcoin, attacks

As per my understanding of the blockchain so far (Bitcoin and Ethereum) nodes and miners have different jobs to do in a blockchain network. Although the terms are extensively used interchangeably, nodes are smaller and more simpler computers which only act as transaction validators and stores a copy of the blockchain each whereas miners are the complex and expensive ones which does all the computation and mine a token of the blockchain and have to keep the proof of work. Now my question is why it's said that theoretically to conduct a successful Sybil attack, one has to gain control of over 51% of the computation power (which of course would be extremely expensive and impractical to do) and not gain control of majority of the nodes (which would be fairly practical to do as compared to the prior) which would give the attacker validation even for the malicious transactions as now he simply would have the majority voting rights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no majority vote in Bitcoin and Ethereum - there is a rule of choosing which of the competing branches of blocks will be joined to the main chain at the nodes of the network. And this rule is the support of the longest of the branches. And for the stable formation of the longest branch, you need to have 51% of the computing power.

Comment: But nodes are the ones who first cross checks every transaction completed and included in the block by the miner and provide "legit" validation for the block to be added in the blockchain isn't it?

Comment: Note that this only applies to proof-of-work, not proof-of-stake, which has a bit different consensus mechanism.

Comment: @Manav Kampani > In Bitcoin and Ethereum, nodes are independent of each other when building a chain and cannot influence other nodes except for the proposal of their candidate block for inclusion in the chain. If the block is formed incorrectly, then it simply will not be accepted by any node.

Comment: @MadJackal that is what I am trying to ask that what if the attacking organization owns majority of the nodes maliciously programmed to accept blocks from their miners?

Comment: The attacker's task is to have his branch of the chain accepted by neutral nodes. And the number of nodes of the attacker has no effect here, since two rules apply to neutral nodes when choosing a chain: 1. the blocks must be valid, 2. The branch must be longer than the competing one

Comment: @MadJackal but what if majority of the nodes are not neutral at the first place and hacked to accept the transactions from the attacking miner? Let me state it like this, what if the ill intended miner tampers with the transactions, create a new illegal block, and broadcasts the illegal block to the network, and since he has control of/hacked the majority of nodes, they simply accept that block and add it to their blockchain as a legal node anyway. And since the miner just has to produce illegal nodes now, it does that quickly enough to form the new longest chain of invalid turned valid nodes?

Comment: The point of PoW is precisely that, regardless of the number of attacking nodes, they will not be able to form an valid "overtaking" chain if they do not have 51% of the network's computing resources. If it quickly forms a chain of not valid blocks, then it simply will not be accepted by neutral nodes, regardless of its length.

Comment: but what if majority of the nodes are not-neutral, would it still not be accepted? Who will decide then that it should be accepted or not?

Comment: I repeat - each node INDEPENDENTLY decides whether or not to accept blocks based on the two rules set out above. Consensuses with explicit voting, where the number of attacking nodes matters, are not PoW or PoS, but a group of BFT consensuses (PBFT, IBFT, and so on)

Comment: ok please consider an example, say there are 5 nodes in a blockchain all neutral, I am an attacker and I introduce my 6 malicious nodes programmed to accept even the invalid blocks(containing tampered/illegal transactions). Now say the current true version of the blockchain is 10 blocks long. Now my miner node mined an invalid block which got accepted by my 6 nodes as their 11th block. Simultaneously a neutral miner node mined a valid block which got added as the 11th block of the blockchain in the 5 neutral nodes. Now their exist 2 versions of the blockchain.

Comment: @MadJackal 6 with the 11th block as X and 5 with the 11th block as Y. Now who will decide which version will persist as the final one, as both the blockchains are valid for their respective nodes.

Comment: The node will save both chains and decide when one of them will lengthen. The current working one will be the one whose initial block is already included in the main chain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132123/discussion-between-manav-kampani-and-mad-jackal).